# How to pass datetime as an argument to a Python MWS library function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, amazon-mws

How do I pass a datetime correctly for the Python MWS Inventory class?

I'm using Python3.6 and the [mws library](https://pymazonian.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mws.html) to query the Amazon MWS api. Amazon API docs say I need to use type DateTime. When I pass a string date time in the argument I get a TypeError: list_inventory_supply() got an unexpected keyword argument 'datetime'

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
from mws import mws

access_key = 'XXX'
merchant_id = 'XXX'
secret_key = 'XXX'

y = mws.Inventory(access_key=access_key, secret_key=secret_key, account_id=merchant_id)

inventory = y.list_inventory_supply(skus=('8F-HMGP-KF2W'), datetime=???, response_group='Basic')
resp_data = inventory.original

print (resp_data)
```

Code works for other reports that don't require a datetime or if I leave out the datetime argument.

Comment: Have you tried sending through the datetime as a string in the format defined by Amazon MWS api?

Comment: Yes. When I use 
`inventory = y.list_inventory_supply(skus=('8F-HMGP-KF2W'), datetime='2019-02-12T19:48:07+00:00', response_group='Basic')`
it returns the same TypeError.

Comment: Do they have a curl example? I've seen many api's that would baulk with that timestamp format. One I'm working with today for example uses 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'. Seeing a curl example will make it clear what the https post call should actually look like.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
current_utc = datetime.utcnow()
dt = current_utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
print(dt)
```

The output is:
'2019-12-12T17:18:16'